# Get number of returned rows in MongoDB query with Java

Tags: java, performance, mongodb, resultset, database-performance

I have a MongoDB 3.2 database. I want to execute a query in Java (MongoDB Java Driver 3.2.1) and to know how many rows have been returned. In other words, I need a `count()` analog of the SQL in MongoDB.

The official MongoDB documentation [proposes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count) to use `myColl.count(query)`, which indeed returns the size of the result set. But the problem is that, as far as I understand, in order to return the number of the result set, this command has to perform the query. Now suppose the query is really «heavy» and I still want to get:

1. the query's result set;
2. the size of the result set (the rows number of query's result set).

In order to achieve my goal should I do:

1. execute a query: `myColl.find(query)` to get a result set;
2. execute one more time absolutely the same query `myColl.count(query)` to get a rows number of the result set.

Is there any more optimal approach, which will less affect the performance?

Comment: If I got the question right, I think once you call `myColl.find(query)` it returns a `DBCursor` object on which you can call `count()` method instead of issuing `myColl.count(query)` to get rows returned by the query.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu, actually it returns `FindIterable<TDocument>` object, which doesn't have `count()` method. In `MongoDB 2.0` there was such method but not in 3.0 version.